# Uncompress data in memory using Boost gzip_decompressor

Tags: c++, boost, compression

I'm trying to decompress binary data in memory using Boost `gzip_decompressor`. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9349726/838), I adapted the following code:

```
vector<char> unzip(const vector<char> compressed)
{
    vector<char> decompressed = vector<char>();

    boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream os;

    os.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
    os.push(boost::iostreams::back_inserter(decompressed));

    boost::iostreams::write(os, &compressed[0], compressed.size());

    return decompressed;
}
```

However, the returned vector has zero length. What am I doing wrong? I tried calling `flush()` on the os stream, but it did not make a difference

Answer (score 3):

Your code works for me with this simple test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>

std::vector<char> unzip(const std::vector<char> compressed)
{
   std::vector<char> decompressed = std::vector<char>();

   boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream os;

   os.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
   os.push(boost::iostreams::back_inserter(decompressed));

   boost::iostreams::write(os, &compressed[0], compressed.size());

   return decompressed;
}

int main() {
   std::vector<char> compressed;
   {
      boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream os;
      os.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_compressor());
      os.push(boost::iostreams::back_inserter(compressed));
      os << "hello\n";
      os.reset();
   }
   std::cout << "Compressed size: " << compressed.size() << '\n';

   const std::vector<char> decompressed = unzip(compressed);
   std::cout << std::string(decompressed.begin(), decompressed.end());

   return 0;
}
```

Are you sure your input was compressed with gzip and not some other method (e.g. raw deflate)?  gzip compressed data begins with bytes `1f 8b`.

I generally use [`reset()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) or put the stream and filters in their own block to make sure that output is complete.  I did both for compression above, just as an example.

Comment: Weird, your example doesn't work for me (produces zero-length output). Perhaps it's a build issue.

Comment: That is odd.  It works for me on OS X 10.7.5 with boost 1.52 and Ubuntu 10.10 with boost 1.53.