# Decompressing gzip file to memory using libarchive

Tags: c++, c, gzip, deflate, libarchive

I'm trying to decompress programmatically a gzip file into memory and mimic the command `gzip -d file.gz` using [libarchive project](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive). 
The file is actually taken from http response with the following header `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`

Here my attempt to read the file. I don't expect not to work since the gzipped file has no entries (it's compressed as a stream) and `archive_read_next_header` tries to read the next file out of the arcihve.

Are there any alternative to this function that extract the entire data out of the compressed file.

```
archive_read_support_format_raw(archive); 
archive_read_support_filter_all(archive);
archive_read_support_compression_all(archive)

archive_read_open_memory(archive, file_data, file_size);
struct archive_entry *entry;
la_ssize_t total, size;
char *buf;    
int status = archive_read_next_header(archive, &entry);
```

Perhaps someone can post minimal code example that resolve this issue ?
Also, Is there an option to find out whether a gzip archive file has entries or not ?

Comment: gzip is not an _archive_ format. You should look for a pure gzip or compression library, `libarchive` expects (as its name implies) a archive.

Comment: @tkausl, thanks for clearing this out. Perhaps you elaborate about the difference between gzip and another compression algorithm that support archiving? furthermore, can you recommend of minimal, ad-hoc and bug-less library that support gzip decompressing (I've examined boost, but i wish to avoid huge deployments of boost's entire logic)

Comment: To decompress a file, ala `gzip -d file.gz` , use [libz](https://www.zlib.net/) to do what you want.

Comment: `Perhaps you elaborate about the difference between gzip and another compression algorithm that support archiving?` which for example? If you think of `tar.gz`, its quite literally a tar archive, which doesn't know anything about compression, compressed with gzip, which doesn't know anything about archives.

Comment: @tkuasl, so if I understand you right, the difference between `tar.gz` and `gzip` is that the first is archived and the second is not.

Comment: Yes, .tar.gz is an gzipped .tar archive, however you can gzip anything, so a .gz file isn't necessarily also an archive.

Answer (score 0):

One possible alternative is to use `boost::iostreams` library which comes with an inbuilt gzip filter and allows exactly what you want - streaming decompression from a gzip file in memory. Here is the reference to the [gzip filter](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/gzip.html), and a snippet from the same:

```
ifstream file("hello.gz", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
filtering_streambuf<input> in;
in.push(gzip_decompressor());
in.push(file);
boost::iostreams::copy(in, cout);
```

Edit: Actually a much better snippet is available here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16693807/3656081

Comment: Hey and thank for you for you answer, I just wonder if you could point me also to an implementation based on zlib. For licencing and deployment reasons , i prefer to avoid using boost.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to do this using `zlib`:

1. Using the inbuilt GzFile API: [Coliru Link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb2f49a59c46eed6) - Read more on this [here](https://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Gzip)

```cpp
int inf(FILE* fp) {
    auto gzf = ::gzdopen(fileno(fp), "r");
    assert(::gztell(gzf) == 0);
    std::cout << "pos: " << ::gztell(gzf) << std::endl;
    ::gzseek(gzf, 18L, SEEK_SET);
    char buf[768] = {0};
    ::gzread(gzf, buf, sizeof(buf)); // use a custom size as needed
    std::cout << buf << std::endl; // Print file contents from 18th char onward
    ::gzclose(gzf);
    return 0;
}
```

2. The native `inflate` API: [Coliru Link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0233686606e0a99d). More on this in the manual link above and [here](https://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html). My code is almost completely a duplicate of the provided link and pretty long, so I wont repost.